# Construction of continuous-time markov chain and finding stationary distribution

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

There are 15 lily pads and 6 frogs. Each frog, with rate 1, jumps to one of the other 9 unoccupied pads chosen uniformly at random.
What is the stationary distribution for the set of occupied lily pads?

This is from Durrett's *Essentials of Stochastic Processes*.

I thought we would consider all possible combinations of occupied pads as states of a continuous-time Markov chain, so $15\choose6$ states. From there I suspect the stationary distribution is $\frac{1}{15\choose6}$ for every state. Is this a correct formulation? I am new to the subject of CTMC's so am not very sure in my answer.

Comment: Do the frogs all jump at once, or one at a time? The wording makes it sound like it is one at a time, but we should be careful about that.

Comment: I think it would be one at a time since each frog has its own rate. I don't have any other information besides that problem statement unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the states all have the same probabilities in the stationary distribution.  This is easy to see once you notice that the process is reversible: given two states $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that a transition from $s_1$ to $s_2$ is possible (by moving one frog), the rate of jumps from $s_1$ to $s_2$ when in state $s_1$ is the same as the rate of jumps from $s_2$ to $s_1$ when in state $s_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! That reasoning makes sense.